A necessary and sufficient condition for $x\in \Lambda^r(V)$ having the form $f_1\wedge \dots \wedge f_r$.
I am reading Shavalievich's Basic Algebraic Geometry. In section 4.1 of chapter 1, when introducing Grassmannian variety, he gave the following fact:
Proposition: Let $V$ be a $n$-dimensional vector space, $r<s$. For $x\in \Lambda^rV$, $x$ can be written as the form $f_1\wedge f_2\wedge \dots \wedge f_r$, iff $(y* x)\wedge x=0$ for all $y\in \Lambda^{r-1}V^*$. (Here $y*x$ means the convolution of a contravariant and a covariant (anti-symmetric) tensor, defined in the previous text of the book.)
So how to show this? I can show the necessity, and the sufficiency remains unclear to me. I can't tell how to 'check' if $x$ cannot be written in this form.
The author didn't give any hints. He gave a reference ([47]), where the concept of convolution was not involved.
Any hints, solutions or references are highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!
Edit: The definition of convolution $y*x$:
$\bullet$ In the book, he defined the bilinear map
$$\begin{aligned} *:\Lambda^sV^*\times \Lambda^rV &\rightarrow \Lambda^{r-s}V\\
(y,x)&\mapsto y*x\end{aligned} $$
called convolution, in the following steps:

When $s=1$, $r=0$, $u*x:=0$.

When $s=1$, $r=1$, $u*x:=u(x)$.

We can extend (linearly) to a unique map $*:V^*\times \Lambda^rV \rightarrow \Lambda^{r-1}V$, if we require:
$$ u*(x\wedge y):=(u*x)\wedge y+(-1)^a (x\wedge (u*y))$$
where $x\in \Lambda^aV$.

Finally, for $u_1\wedge \dots \wedge u_s\in \Lambda^s V^* $ and $x\in \Lambda^r V$, define:
$$ (u_1\wedge \dots \wedge u_s)*x:=u_1*(u_2* \dots * (u_s*x)\dots )$$
We can show that it is well-defined, and we extend it linearly to a map
$*:\Lambda^sV^*\times \Lambda^rV \rightarrow \Lambda^{r-s}V$.


$\bullet$ My attempt:
I found that (I hope it is right) in terms of basis we can define the convolution in the following way, satisfying all the above:
Let $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ be a basis of $V$, then we define:
$$\begin{aligned}
&(u_1\wedge \dots \wedge u_s)*(e_{\alpha_1}\wedge \dots \wedge e_{\alpha_r})\\
:= &\sum_{i_1<\dots<i_s} (-1)^{\sum_j (i_j-1)} (u_1\wedge \dots \wedge u_s)(e_{\alpha_{i_1}},\dots,e_{\alpha_{i_s}}) e_{\alpha_1}\wedge \dots \wedge \widehat{e_{\alpha_{i_1}}}\wedge \dots \wedge \widehat{e_{\alpha_{i_s}}} \wedge \dots \wedge e_{\alpha_r}
\end{aligned} $$

Can you write out the definition of $y*x$?

@NicholasTodoroff Sure, I have added them in the post.

As I thought, this "convolution" is also (more commonly?) known as the (left) interior product.

Given $x \in \Lambda^r V$ we define $T(x) = \{a \in V: a \wedge x = 0\}$. Clearly, $T(x) \subset V$ is a linear subspace.
Observation. For a nonzero $x \in \Lambda^r V$ the space $T(x)$ has dimension $d \le r$ and for any basis $f_1, \dots, f_d$ in $T(x)$ there exists $x' \in \Lambda^{r-d}V$ such that $x = f_1 \wedge \dots \wedge f_d \wedge x'$.
Corollary. A nonzero $x \in \Lambda^r V$ is the product of $r$ vectors in $V$ iff $\dim T(x) = r$.
I recommend to prove these facts as an exercise, but if you need a proof I can suggest to consult the first chapter of Federer's book Geometric measure theory (imo, it is a great exposition of exterior algebras).
Now consider $x \in \Lambda^r V$ such that $d = \dim T(x) < r$. We can consider a basis $f_1, \dots, f_n$ of $V$ such that $f_1, \dots, f_d$ form the basis of $T(x)$. Let $L = \mathrm{Span}\{f_{d+1}, \dots, f_n\}$ is the corresponding complement of $T(x)$ in $V$. From the observation we can express $x = f_1 \wedge \dots \wedge f_d \wedge x'$, where $x' \in \Lambda^{r-d} L$. Let $f_1^*, \dots, f_n^*$ denote the dual basis of the space $V^*$ and identify $T(x)^* = \mathrm{Span}\{f_1^*, \dots, f_d^*\}$, $L^* = \{f_{d+1}^*, \dots, f_n^*\}$. We shall find $y \in \Lambda^{r-1}V^*$ such that $(y*x)\wedge x \ne 0$. Clearly, it suffices to find $z \in \Lambda^{r-d-1}L$ such that $(z * x') \wedge x'\ne 0$ and consider $y = f_1^* \wedge \dots \wedge f_d^* \wedge z$. But now we can utilize the fact that $T(x) \cap L = \{0\}$: this implies that $a \wedge x' \ne 0$ for all nonzero $a \in L$. Therefore, it suffices to find arbitrary $z \in \Lambda^{r-1}L$ such that $z * x'\ne 0$. But the existence of such $z$ for any nonzero $x'$ should be an easy exercise.

Thank you for your elegant proof! The observation is a quite strong statement.

After discussing with my instructor, he gave me the following key idea, from which I formulate a (elementary) proof:
Lemma: Suppose $0\neq x\in \Lambda^rV$, then there exists $0\neq y\in \Lambda^{r-1}V^*$, such that
$$ y*x\neq 0$$
Proof of the lemma:
Write $x=\sum\limits_{i_1<\dots<i_r}A^{i_1\dots i_r}e_{i_1}\wedge\dots \wedge e_{i_r}$, then we compute:
$$\begin{aligned}
y*x &=(-1)^{\frac{r(r-1)}{2}}\sum_{i_1<\dots<i_r} A^{i_1\dots i_r} \sum_{j=1}^r (-1)^{j-1} y(e_{i_1},\dots,\widehat{e_{i_j}},\dots,e_{i_r}) e_{i_j}\\
&=(-1)^{\frac{r(r-1)}{2}} \sum_{k=1}^n\left(\sum_{i_1<\dots<i_r, k=i_{l}} (-1)^{l-1} A^{i_1\dots i_r} y(e_{i_1},\dots,\widehat{e_{k}},\dots,e_{i_r})\right)e_k
\end{aligned} $$
We can always find some $k$ and $i_1<\dots<i_r$ with $k=i_l$, such that $A^{i_1\dots i_r}\neq 0$. Then we can choose $y$ by defining:
$$ y:=B_{j_1\dots j_{r-1}}e^{j_1}\wedge \dots \wedge e^{j_{r-1}},\quad B_{j_1\dots j_{r-1}}:=\begin{cases} 1 \quad &(j_1,\dots,j_{r-1})=(i_1,\dots,\widehat{k},\dots,i_r)\\
0 \quad &\mbox{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
Proof of the proposition:
$\bullet$ Necessity: Suppose $x=f_1\wedge \dots \wedge f_r$. We know from definition that $y*x\in \mathrm{span}\{f_1,\dots,f_r\}$, which implies that
$ (y*x)\wedge x=0$.
$\bullet$ Sufficiency: Suppose
$$ (y*x)\wedge x=0\quad \forall y\in \Lambda^{r-1}V^*$$
Since $x\neq 0$, we can find $0\neq y_1$ such that $f_1:=y_1*x\neq 0$. Extend $f_1$ to a basis $B_1:=\{f_1,f_2,\dots,f_n\}$ and expand $x$ in terms of the basis $\{f_{i_1}\wedge \dots \wedge f_{i_r}\}$.
Since $ f_1\wedge x=0$, we know every term in the expansion has the form
$$ A^{1i_2\dots i_r}f_1\wedge f_{i_2}\wedge \dots \wedge f_{i_r} $$
Hence $x$ has the form $f_1\wedge x_1$. Here, $0\neq x_1\in \Lambda^{r-1}V_1$, where $V_1$ is the subspace spanned by $\{f_2,\dots,f_n\}$.
Now, if $r-1=1$, we are done. If $r-1>1$, we will apply a similar argument to $x_1$. For this purpose, we need to show that:
$$ (y_1*x_1)\wedge x_1=0\qquad \forall y_1\in \Lambda^{r-2}V_1^*$$
Indeed, set $y:=f_1^*\wedge y_1$, by definition of convolution, we have:
$$ \begin{aligned} 
0&= \left((f_1^*\wedge y_1)*x\right)\wedge x\\
&=\left(f_1^**(y_1*x)\right)\wedge x\\
&=\left(f_1^**\big((\underbrace{y_1*f_1}_{\in k}) x_1-f_1\wedge (y_1*x_1)\big)\right)\wedge x\\
&=-(y_1*x_1)\wedge x
\end{aligned}$$
Therefore: $\big((y_1*x_1)\wedge x_1\big)\wedge f_1=0$. But $f_1\notin V_1$, we can easily deduce that $(y_1*x_1)\wedge x_1=0$. Therefore the previous argument can be applied to $x_1$ again, and we finish the proof by induction.
